# Is there a Laravel plugin that manage scopes?

Tags: php, laravel

I found a lot of Laravel plugins that manage roles, but what I need is limit the numbers of results based on a the role.

For instance, I have a hierarchical organization:

Federations -> Association -> Clubs

Each of those structure has president, so I would like that a federation president can see all association / clubs / users that corresponds, etc for each kind of user.

Is there a plugin that has been made to manage different kind of users, with different scopes on models?

Comment: Absolutely, you are referring to what is known as a ORM (object relational mapper). Laravel has one included called Eloquent.

Comment: Yes you should try with Boilerplate(https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate)